# SMS not sending with IntentService

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I'm trying to send messages to certain phone numbers using an IntentService, but I don't know why I am not receiving the messages. Here is my code:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

public NotificationService() {
    super(NotificationService.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String number, message;

    number = (String) intent.getExtras().get("NUMBER");
    message = (String) intent.getExtras().get("MESSAGE");

    sendMessage(number, message);
}

private void sendMessage(String number, String message) {
    final Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
    startActivity(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, pendingIntent, null);
}
}
```

This is where I call the Service

```
private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.send_button:
                number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                message = mComposeMessage.getText().toString();
                if (number.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0){
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NotificationService.class);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
                    startService(serviceIntent);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.cancel_button:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

And this is in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<service android:name=".service.NotificationService"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: check if your app has **android.permission.SEND_SMS** permission granted, from api 23 (marshmallow) you need to explicitly ask for permission which are categorized as dangerous, search how to ask for permission explicitly if you have any doubt.

Comment: I already changed my targetSdkVersion to 22.